# Auto increment in Oracle package

Tags: oracle, package, auto-increment

I am trying to use autoincrement on my package without using trigger.. Can someone explain me how I have to use it in my package.. I did this way didnt work its complaining abt variable not being declared or type not assigned.. I saw other autoincrement questions but nobody has used auto increment without trigger on package

```
 PROCEDURE insertExample   (  
user_id_in IN sample.seq_user_id.nextval,   
name_in IN sample.name%TYPE,     
age_in IN sample.age%TYPE   )   
IS    
BEGIN      
INSERT INTO sample    
 (seq_user_id.nextval, name, age)     
VALUES     
(user_id_in, name_in, age_in);    
END insertExample;
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you wanting to allow a custom user_id to be passed in or always use the sequence?

In the first case, you would need something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertexample (
   user_id_in   in   sample.user_id%type,
   name_in      in   sample.name%type,
   age_in       in   sample.age%type
)
IS
BEGIN
   insert into sample
               (user_id, name, age
               )
        values (nvl(user_id_in, seq_user_id.nextval), name_in, age_in);
END insertexample;
```

If you always want to use the sequence (which is probably the right choice), just take out that input parameter and the NVL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertexample (
   name_in      in   sample.name%type,
   age_in       in   sample.age%type
)
IS
BEGIN
   insert into sample
               (user_id, name, age
               )
        values (seq_user_id.nextval, name_in, age_in);
END insertexample;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want something like

```
PROCEDURE insertExample   (  
name_in IN sample.name%TYPE,     
age_in IN sample.age%TYPE   )   
IS    
BEGIN      
  INSERT INTO sample    
   (user_id, name, age)     
  VALUES     
   (seq_user_id.nextval, name_in, age_in);    
END insertExample;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your not that far away from a working solution:

```
PROCEDURE insertExample   (
  name_in IN sample.name%TYPE,     
  age_in  IN sample.age%TYPE   )   
IS    
BEGIN      
  INSERT INTO sample (user_id, name, age)     
  VALUES (seq_user_id.nextval, name_in, age_in);    
END insertExample;
```

I'm assuming that the table has at least three columns called `user_id`, `name` and `age`. Furthermore, I'm assuming that you have already created a sequence called `seq_user_id` (CREATE SEQUENCE seq_user_id START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1).

As the user Id is not automatically assigned, it is no longer part of the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase your procedure as a FUNCTION instead, and return the new ID to the caller:

```
FUNCTION insert_user
(
    name_in IN users.name%TYPE,     
    age_in  IN users.age%TYPE   
)
    RETURN users.id%TYPE 
IS
    v_id users.id%TYPE;
BEGIN      
    INSERT INTO users (
        user_id, 
        name, 
        age
    ) VALUES (
        seq_user_id.nextval, 
        name_in, 
        age_in
    )
    RETURNING
        user_id
    INTO
        v_id
    ;    
    RETURN v_id;
END insert_user;
```

This is generally a more useful pattern for inserts, especially where you may want to subsequently insert child records in other tables.